# pycurl.error: (1, 'Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl') Ubuntu

Tags: python, pycurl

After I installed pycurl, there is an error occured like this when I test my code.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

python: 3.6.5

curl: 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8

pycurl: 7.43.0.1

Is there any solution I can solve that? Thank you !

Comment: What libcurl packages do you have installed  ( sudo dpkg -l | grep -i libcurl )?

Comment: @visibleman                    ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64               7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8                          amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libcurl4-gnutls-dev:amd64           7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8                          amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)

Comment: Did you install pycurl using pip? Were both libcurl libraries installted when you installed pycurl? The only thing I can think of, is that  If both the libcurl libraries where not in place when installing pycurl with pip, I suspect you might end up with https disabled.

Comment: @visibleman Yes, I found curl package doesn't find the path of ssl. However,  there comes another problem after I enable ssl. The error message is : ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other). Why are there so many problems coming one by one? omg.

Comment: I think I would try to remove pycurl using pip, and then remove all the curl packages using apt/dpkg. Then reinstall curl and libcurl using apt, then reinstall pycurl using pip. Sorry, that's all I've got.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for ssl

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

or you can configure CURL with ssl

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I solved the problem finally.

Here are 2 errors I face:

**pycurl.error: (1, 'Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl')**

**ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other).**

**Solution:**

1)apt-get install openssl

2)export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl

3)easy_install pycurl

For some reason, the pip ingore the PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY. I have to use easy_install.